# How can I set the offset on a straight line in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, path, linear-gradients

I want to make a linear gradient on a straight line.But the offset always remains constant does not change because it is a straight line.
For example, the first stop is color red and the second stop is color blue, but the offset is a single color.

```
<defs>
<linearGradient id="Gradientm5cf5" x1="11.111" x2="33.111" y1="44.111" y2="77.111" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
<stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<path d="M 1518 1131 L 1681.63 1131" fill="none" stroke="url(#Gradientm5cf5)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" stroke-width="6" style="--animation-time:1s;" class="flow">
</path>
```

[image: Like this example]

Comment: Your x1, y1, x2, y2 don't really match the path co-ordinates. They need to for your gradient to work.

Comment: thank you @RobertLongson. I solve this problem when I changed coordinates it has worked for me.